# How Calculate Stored Potential Energy of Pressurized Water

Tags: fluid-mechanics

This is a real-life question. I work in construction. Several engineers involved have come up with different answers. Which one is correct, and why?

We are developing the plan to hydrotest a tunnel. The tunnel is 2438mm in diameter and will be used to transport potable water within a municipality. To start with, we're working on a section of that tunnel (between valves) that contains 100,000 litres of water that has been pressurized from zero to to 2261 kPa. What is the stored potential energy of the water? The stored potential energy is critical to our safety plan.

One colleague used Bermoulli's principal and came up with 113 kJ. Another used the compressibility factor of water and came up with 226,000 kJ.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: How sure are you that all the air has been removed from the section being tested? if 10% of the volume was air then you have 10k liters of gas being compressed to that pressure which has a very different energy storage potential than water.

Comment: If the fluid is not moving during (successful) test, you don't need Bernoulli's principle. The second value could be correct, I would suggest using second formula from [this source](https://www.nist.gov/system/files/documents/2020/03/24/NCNR%20Pressure%20Vessel%20Stored%20Energy%20Limit%20Calculation.pdf).

Comment: The stored strain energy in a material from pressurization is $P^2V/2K$ (absolute pressure $P$, volume $V$), where the [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) and the temperature are assumed constant. But note the caveats in the other comments.

Comment: So why is one double the other? examine them both and see what got missed or included... If you showed both calculations in detail...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, we are 100% we'll get all the air out of the system prior to testing. Tomas, I really appreciate that link.

Comment: Everyone in my office agrees that the 100,000 litres will expand 110 litres when pressurized to 2261 kPa. Engineer A then used this formula: Energy = 0.5 * pressure / density * volume. He got 113 kJ. 
Engineer B used: Energy = pressure * volume. He got 226,000 kJ. They're both certain they're right. Engineer C used the sam formula as Eng A, but used only the 110 litres of additional water, not the total volume.

Comment: Any of these formulas could be simplified versions, since we're dealing with water at sea level at 15 or 20ºC.

Comment: Some additional energy will be stored using the elasticity of the pipe. I suspect that may be far more significant.

Comment: @GregLocock thanks for that comment. I hadn't considered it. The system was designed to withstand large seismic events so the pipe is a custom alloy with high ductility. Yes, I suspect it would affect the pressure.

Comment: Dimensional analysis of (0.5 * pressure / density * volume). comes out all wrong: J.m.m.m / kg.  Dimension of (pressure x volume) is Joules, but the scale is wrong (integration error). These are "engineers" ???

Comment: Yes, @david, they are professional engineers and I am not.  I am on the operations side of construction, where I try to build what the engineers design.  I wish I knew which guy was right.

Comment: They are both wrong -- unless you have misunderstood what they have said, they are both grotesquely wrong. Tell A that until he gets his dimensional analysis right, you're ignoring everything he says about anything. Give B @Chemomechanics formula and ask him if he understands where he went wrong.  Tell your boss that these guys are the wrong guys to ask.